# Can PHP's random_int be relied for unique integer genrator (reasonably)

Tags: php, random, integer, uniqueidentifier

I have an application, which will require around 200K batch IDs to be generated every year.

I first thought of using `uniqid()` to generate batch IDs, but this will return be string, which will take up huge space in database, as compared to integer.

Hence, my question is, will `random_int(1, 2147483647)` be relied upon to generate unique numbers?

FYI, generally `2147483647` is `PHP_INT_MAX`.

Comment: Why does it need to be random?

Comment: And no you can't rely on a random number to be unique across the whole set

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, It does not need to be random. Just unique.

Comment: then use an incremental value like a db id

Comment: `uniqid()` strings are 13 bytes, your integers are 4. That's a difference of 9 bytes, times 200K records = 1,800,000 bytes. That's less than 2Mb per year of records, which is not remotely "huge" space. That said, if space and performance are such a concern, why are you running on a 32 bit system?

Comment: There's too little information to help you specifically with what you need, as it seems that there are a few good feasible solutions to the issue you raise, but only in general

use a db auto increment
do use a uniqid with a year prefix
Regarding your question, that's just statistics... repeating 200k out of 2bn is 1/10,000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Alex Howansky, there is very little increase in database size if you use `uniquid()`.

If your requirement is near 100% unique IDs then `random` 4-bit integers will just not be unique. It will need some extra bits to be random and unique.

I use below function in my applications. This has a higher probability of being unique. It uses 22 bytes instead of 13 by `uniquid()`

```
function getUniqueId(){
  // will return 22 characters Unique string eg "5bcc2342652c2630171474"
  return str_replace('.', '', uniqid('',true));
}
```

If you still need to use integer only. Then, as suggested by Lawrence Cherone, you should use auto increment.